# Kubernetes get ingress tls.hosts from pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

Using Kubernetes is there a way from other pods to get the `ingress.spec.tls.hosts` value without using `kubectl` *(DNS, ENVVAR, OTHER)*?

I know I can do:

```
# in other pod
dig +short my-app.default.svc.cluster.local
172.20.203.19

echo $MY_APP_SERVICE_HOST
172.20.203.19

echo $MY_APP_SERVICE_PORT
3000
```

Or:

```
# in other pod
dig +short SRV my-app.default.svc.cluster.local
0 100 3000 my-app.default.svc.cluster.local.
```

But I actually want to connect to the external load balancer of `my-app` which has an ingress definition of:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.mydomain.com
  rules:
  - host: myapp.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: http
```

So, I want to dynamically get `myapp.mydomain.com` from pods.

Answer (score 1):

Use the kubernetes api to get an ingress resource. Create a role, associate it with a service account, then list your ingresses using curl for instance. An example below for the default namespace and service account:

```
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-clusterrole
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["ingresses"]
  verbs: ["*"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ingress-clusterrolebinding
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  name: ingress-clusterrole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
subjects:
  - name: default
    namespace: default
    kind: ServiceAccount
```

```sh
curl --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernet
es.io/serviceaccount/token)" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://kubernetes.default.svc/ap
is/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses | jq '.items'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider access Kubernetes API from a separate Pod using particular [*Service Account*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/), leveraging [Bearer token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#putting-a-bearer-token-in-a-request) authentication strategy through a specific token propagation inside Pod, identifying target `ServiceAccount` credentials and permissions according to [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) rules authorization enforcement; thanks @Rodrigo Loza for his efforts sharing a nice example pointing out about this.

However, if you distinguish RBAC permissions across different service accounts in the same namespace, you might be aware and supply the corresponded [credentials](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod) for the relevant service account inside the target Pod:

```
spec:
  serviceAccountName: somename
```

According to the official K8s documentation:

> When you create a pod, if you do not specify a service account, it is
>   automatically assigned the **default** service account in the same
>   namespace. If you get the raw json or yaml for a pod you have created
>   (for example, *kubectl get pods/ -o yaml*), you can see the
>   **spec.serviceAccountName** field has been automatically set.

I would also encourage you to learn more about authentication strategies in the K8s documentation [guidelines](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#authentication-strategies).